# Group theory — Lagrange's theorem does not seem to hold

Tags: discrete-mathematics, group-theory

As per Lagrange's theorem, the order of a subgroup must perfectly divide the order of the group.

Let us take the group $G = (S, \sharp)$, where $S = \{1,3,5,7,9\}$ and
$\sharp$ suggests multiplication mod 10.  $G$ is a group, with being
$O(G)=5$

Let us take a subset $H = \{1,3,7,9\}$, then $(H, \sharp)$ is also a group as it is closed, associative, satisfies identity and inverse laws. Thus $H$ is a subgroup of $S$.  $O(H) = 4$.
But I don't see Lagrange's theorem holding, as 4 does not divide 5.

Not sure if I'm making any silly mistake somewhere, would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: We prefer that you not delete your question after receiving an answer.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful to others in the future, and answerers may be answering on this basis.  As such, deleting your question after receiving an answer can potentially be perceived as impolite.  Thank you for your understanding!

Comment: Is this question on-topic here?  Any community votes?

Comment: @D.W. I would say migrating this to the Mathematics stack exchange is a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original $G$ is not a group:

$$5~\sharp~5 = 25 \mod 10 = 5$$

If $5$ had an inverse then by multiplying by $5^{-1}$ on both sides we get:

$$5=(5^{-1}~\sharp~5)~\sharp~5=5^{-1}~\sharp~(5~\sharp~5) = 5^{-1}~\sharp~5 = 1$$

Which is clearly not correct. Hence $5$ doesn't have an inverse in $G$.

Comment: More snappily, no multiple of $5$ ends in "$1$" in base $10$.